# Import an XSLT style-sheet with applied style-sheet parameter

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How does one import a style-sheet, applying an actual parameter value
to the called style-sheet? Here is an illustration.

Let's say I have a general purpose style-sheet which takes a parameter "x".
It looks like this, and is located at "general.xslt".

```
 <xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   version="2.0">
 <xsl:param name="x" as="xs:string" />
 ... style-sheet content ...
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have a higher level style-sheet (specific.xslt) which wants to incorporate the functionality of general.xslt by importation. This higher level style-sheet (specific.xslt) takes a parameter "y". The higher level style-sheet needs to import
general.xslt applying an actual parameter, being some function
of y, to the formal parameter x. If this were legal XSLT 2.0 syntax, it would read some-thing like this:

higher level style-sheet:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   version="2.0">
 <xsl:param name="y" as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:import href="general.xslt">
  <xsl:with-param name="x" select="some-function($y)" />
 </xsl:import>

 <xsl:function name="some-function" as="xs:string">
   <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:string" />
   ... content goes here ...
 </xsl:function>

 ... more content ...

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course the above is not legal syntax, but it illustrates what I want to achieve - invoke style-sheets with actual parameters in a similar way to to invoking templates with parameters. Is this possible in any version of XSLT?

**Illustration of Michael Kay's Answer**

general.xslt:
This low-level style-sheet takes a parameter. The formal parameter is x.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   version="2.0"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn">
 <xsl:param name="x" as="xs:string" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
   The value of x is <xsl:value-of select="$x" />
  </root>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

specific.xslt:
This high-level style-sheet takes a parameter. The formal parameter is y.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:my="http://my.com"
   version="2.0"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn my">
 <xsl:import href="general.xslt" />
 <xsl:param name="y" as="xs:string" />

 <xsl:function name="my:some-function" as="xs:string">
   <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:string" />
   <xsl:value-of select="concat( $value, '!') " />
 </xsl:function>
 <xsl:variable name="x" select="my:some-function($y)" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-imports/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command line invocation of Saxon:**

```
 Transform.exe -s:specific.xslt -xsl:specific.xslt -o:specific-out.xml y=abc
```

**Output:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>The value of x is abc!</root>
```

The actual parameter of general.xslt is 'abc!'

Comment: Sorry, but as hard as I tried to understand what is asked here, I couln't. Stylesheets aren't called -- this is confusing. What you actually want to achieve?  Could you, please, edit the question to make it more meaningful?

Comment: Yes you are right, style-sheets are imported or included, not called. Question updated accordingly. At some point in the compilation, an imported style-sheet's formal parameters need to be bound to some specific actual values. The thrust of the question is how to bind that value in a calling stylesheet. Michael's answer is that you define a param or variable in the calling stylesheet, of the same name. I was surprised by this. Coming from a procedural background, I was expecting a similar parameter binding mechanism that you would use if calling a named template or function.

Comment: Yes, here we have import precedence rules. Any global variable in an importing stylesheet module is visible in any of the imported (directly or indirectly) stylesheets and overrides any identically named variables in any of these stylesheet modules. This is so, because the `xsl:import` statements always must come before any other global-level statement. So aglobal `xsl:variable always comes after any `xsl:import` and has higher priority .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the xsl:param with an xsl:param or xsl:variable (appearing at the top level, i.e a child of xsl:stylesheet in the importing module).

```
<xsl:variable name="x" select="some-function($y)" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I bought your book btw. I would recommend it to any one. The best part about it was the Knight's Tour chapter - that was really enjoyable.